# Show that MLE of $\theta$ is consistent for $N(\theta, \theta)$ distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I want to show that the MLE of $N(\theta, \theta) $, namely :
$$\theta_1 = \frac { \sqrt{1+\frac 4 n \sum^n x_i^2} } 2 $$ converges in probability towards the true parameter $ \theta$. I thought about showing that the mean square error converges to zero but I don't know the law of $\theta_1$.

What can I do? I want to show that it converges in probability and if possible also to find the law when $n\to \infty$ of $\theta_1$.

Comment: Applying the Strong Law of Large numbers tells us that almost surely $$\theta_1\to \frac 12\sqrt{1+4(\theta+\theta^2)}=\frac 12 (2\theta+1) =\theta+\frac 12$$ So I don't see where it went wrong? Maybe you need to subtract something to make it right? BTW convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability.

Comment: I dont get how the sum got transformed. Maybe you can detail a little bit what s going on with the Strong law? Or is it just as the answer is saying?

Comment: yeah basically. Just define $Y_i=X_i^2$ and show that $Y_i$ satisfies the SLLN (or WLLN if you wish).

Comment: Do you mean the variance is $\theta^2$? And are you presuming $\theta \ge 0$?

Comment: It is the MLE of $\theta$, not 'MLE of $N(\theta,\theta)$'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the WLLN
$$
1/n \sum X_i^2 \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{E}X^2=Var(X)+\mathbb{E}^2X=\theta+\theta^2.
$$
as $n \to \infty$,
and 
$$
g(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4 x}}{2}
$$
it a continuous transformation. Hence by the continuous mapping theorem, 
$$
g\left( \sum X_i^2/n \right) \xrightarrow{p}g(\theta + \theta^2)=\frac{ \sqrt{(1+2\theta)^2}}{2} = 1/2+\theta,
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I know the WLLN with the sum of X_i, it is also working with the sum of the square? With a simple substitution? (i m not trolling never thought about that).

Comment: And shoudlnt it converges to something a little different? It seems you wrote g( theta/2) in the last line. Or did i miss something?

Comment: 1. You can denote $X_i ^2 = Y_i$ and then proceed as usual with the WLLN. 2. $g(\theta + \theta^2) = \sqrt{ 1 + 4(\theta + \theta^2) }/2 = \sqrt{ 1 + 2\times 2 \theta + 2^2\theta^2}/2 = \sqrt{ (1 + 2\theta)^2}/2 $

Comment: yes thank you for the explaination. Got confused when I read the answer (i was really tired)